# Check if a List is not empty and not null simultaneously in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a

`List<Object> coins = exchange.getCoins();`

I want to simplify the below code which is in java below 8.

```
if (coins != null && !coins.isEmpty()) {
    //perform logic
}
```

The thing is that after the check I have lot of operation to perform, so I want to have a stream approach.

Comment: I don't see how you could get much simpler tbh.

Comment: I mean something like `coins.stream()....`

Comment: I agree with George. I'll add, that if you're the one writing `getCoins`, it's probably best to make sure an empty list is returned instead of `null`

Comment: one of the ways to simplify that would require you to ensure that `exchange.getCoins()` **does not** return a `null` value and then you can ignore the empty check as you proceed with `coins.stream...`

Answer (score 1):

Just try use:

```
Stream.ofNullable(coins).filter(...).map(...).collect(..)
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
Optional.ofNullable(coins).ifPresent(e-> 
                       e.stream()
                        .filter(x-> x.length()>0)
                        .map(...)
                        .collect(...))
```